# In React redux state array of objects i can't update the state it creates error A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

**the component that dispatch the state**

```
const [personalInfo, setPersonalInfo] = useState([]);
dispatch(addPersonalInfo(personalInfo));
```

**action**

```
import * as types from './actionTypes';
export default function addPersonalInfo(personalInfo) {
  return { type: types.ADD_PERSONAL_INFO, personalInfo };
}
```

**reducer**

```
import * as types from '../actions/actionTypes';

export default function personalInfoReducer(state = [], action) {
  debugger;
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_PERSONAL_INFO:
      return [...state, {...action.personalInfo}];
    case types.UPDATE_PERSONAL_INFO: {
      const newArray = [...state];
      const updatedArray = [
        ...newArray.filter((person) => person.id !== action.personalInfo.id),
        Object.assign({}, action.personalInfo),
      ];
      return [...state, {...updatedArray}];
    }

    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

**Sample data inside redux**
[image]

**the error am getting**
A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path `personalInfoReducer.0.0.firstName`. This may cause incorrect behavior.

Comment: What you are doing is conceptually wrong the state can be either local or global but not both at the same time. If you need to keep 'personalInfo' in the global state, then remove the `useState()` hook and read/write 'personalInfo' from/to the global state (using `connect()` from `react-redux` to map state and actions to props).

Comment: As I see action.personalInfo is an Array, so you did [..state, action.personalInfo] and got [[]] structure. I see that personalInfor shoul be Object that you add in to the []. May be you should  change `const [personalInfo, setPersonalInfo] = useState({});`

Comment: now i updated to array of objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of updating array of objects you can Dispatch each objects into Redux with unique Id to filter.